# Comparing/exporting FLA files

Tags: flash, fla

Is there a way of exporting an FLA file to a human-readable format, so that different revisions of a file can be compared?

I found a script for exporting to XML here (post 6):
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=155434
 -- but it doesn't work as advertised - e.g. it doesn't export any details of items in the library.

Answer (score 2):

As i know it was designed to dump only the Library from the Fla file. I have an upgraded version (`diff_fla`):

- https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/fla/diff_fla

You will find 3 script files:

- FlaToXML.jsfl:
  xml generator, uses Adobe Flash GUI to produce xml-s.
- diff_perforce.py:
  python comparator, uses xml generator and compares 2 xml using p4merge tool.
- diff_perforce.bat:
  python comparator wrapper, invokes from the Perforce GUI application.

It works with the Adove Flash CS3.

For the details, see the README_EN.txt in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the XFL file format may be of interest to you:

http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000269.html

Comment: It'll be supported in Flash CS5, which releases in a few months or so.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as .fla files are intended to be used exclusively through Adobe's proprietary software. To keep track of revisions, I would suggest keeping your .fla files in some kind of [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/), or [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I also need this but I wasn't able to find a way to diff .fla files.

Adobe is advertising that Flash CS5 will feature XML based .fla files. We'll just have to wait it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CS5, you can save your project in XFL format, which is XML based

More info about XFL here: http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=1986